# Can't dismiss a topic request because I have voted on it (although I didn't)?

Tags: bug, documentation

I just tried to dismiss [this topic request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topic-requests/5727) as "is not necessary", but I get this error-message:

> You've already voted on this topic request.

But I have never voted for this request and as you can see, the number of votes is **0**.

[image: topic request screenshot]

Is this a bug or is there maybe a other reason, why I can't dismiss this request?

Comment: Did you perhaps vote and then retract your vote?

Comment: @CodyGray no. This request is quite new and it is clearly not necessary. I would never vote for such a request. And I don't believe, that I voted AND retracted the vote accidentally

Comment: could you have already dismiss voted it?

Comment: Looks like it because when a user creates a Topic Request it starts with one vote (his own). So if it's 0 maybe you already dismissed...